# R Create Matrix From an Operation on a "Row" Vector and a "Column" Vector

Tags: r, vector, transpose

First create a "row" vector and a "column" vector in R:

```
> row.vector <- seq(from = 1, length = 4, by = 1)
> col.vector <- {t(seq(from = 1, length = 3, by = 2))}
```

From that I'd like to create a matrix by, e.g., multiplying each value in the row vector with each value in the column vector, thus creating from just those two vectors:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    5
[2,]    2    6   10
[3,]    3    9   15
[4,]    4   12   20
```

Can this be done with somehow using `apply()`? `sweep()`? ...a `for` loop?

*Thank you for any help!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd be better off working with two actual vectors, instead of a vector and a matrix:

```
outer(row.vector,as.vector(col.vector))

#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    3    5
#[2,]    2    6   10
#[3,]    3    9   15
#[4,]    4   12   20
```

Comment: Ah, very good, thelatemail.  I didn't know about `outer`.  That's good to know to use col."vector" as an actual vector. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Simple matrix multiplication will work just fine

```
row.vector %*% col.vector
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    3    5
# [2,]    2    6   10
# [3,]    3    9   15
# [4,]    4   12   20
```

Comment: Thank you, MrFlick.  I simplified my question a lot to try to make it more generalizable for others. should have been clearer, in fact the operations I want to perform is more complicated than multiplication (if `row.vector -> r` and `col.vector -> c`, then I'll be computing `(exp(r - c)/(1 + exp(r - c)))`, but your answer is very helpful and generalizable enough to help others who read this.

Comment: @wes Then my recommendation would have looked a lot like @thelatemail's with a custom function `outer(r, as.vector(c), FUN=function(r,c) (exp(r-c)/(1+exp(r-c))))`

Comment: Yes, that's very elegant.  Thank you yet again!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to get there with `apply`.  Is there a reason why you're not using `matrix`?

```
> apply(col.vector, 2, function(x) row.vector * x)
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]    1    3    5
## [2,]    2    6   10
## [3,]    3    9   15
## [4,]    4   12   20
```

Comment: I'm pretty new at R, so I'm just not sure how I would use `matrix` to perform operations (and not just create matrices).  Using your answer to address my _real_ issue (which I didn't present before to keep it useful to others, I use your answer to produce `answer = apply(col.vector, 2, function(x) {exp(row.vector - x)/(1 + exp(row.vector - x))})` which works like a charm!  Should I update my questions to reflect answers to both levels of my question (the simple multiplication one and the logistic one)?  Thanks, Richard Scriven!